# pyCharm: Unresolved reference "MIMEMultipart"

Tags: python, pycharm

The IDE pyCharm thinks "MIMEMultipart" is an unresolved reference:

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
```

The is a red warning on the right hand side bar.

Up to now every red warning on this side bar was correct and broken code. But here the code works.

What's wrong here: my usage of MIMEMultipart or pyCharm?

Comment: Do you use any virtualenv which is unknown to pycharm? Do you run your script using pycharm or in some other way? Which python version?

Comment: `ctrl-click` on `email` and take a look at the source of this module. `email` uses a somewhat fancy dynamic import mechanism that PyCharm just can't follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must write in this way:

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

Comment: ok, I use your way of importing. Where do you have this answer from? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I check the examples from the python docs. You are right, they use email.mime, too. Thank you.